# constant propagation after register allocation

Tags: c++, assembly, compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization

I am wondering why it is not advisable to do constant propagation after register allocation (RA) as well. After several optimization passes (post RA) there is scope for peephole optimizations like constant propagation/dead-code elimination etc.
I can think of only two reasons,

1. that these optimizations are easy to do on SSA form.
2. peephole opt. post RA will result in increased compilation time.

Are there any other reasons?

If it is okay to perform peephole opt. post RA then what should be the data structures/algorithms (any paper, reference etc. would be helpful).

EDIT:
in response to  500 - Internal Server Error's comment.
After optimization passes like phi-elimination (which is, e.g., in llvm-clang, merged with register allocation), global scheduling like: pulling up instructions to parent basic blocks etc.

EDIT2:

[image: Passes]

In the example shown in figure:
The register allocator figures out that v1 and v2 has the same value and hence, assigns same register (r1) to them. After register allocation a common sub-expression elimination
pass can eliminate `r2 = r1` from basic block #4.

Comment: A better question would be: What benefit goes constant-propagation after register-allocation have over before register-allocation?

Comment: What potential for constant propagation could be discovered after register allocation that couldn't as easily (easier, probably) have been detected before?

Comment: @Mysticial, I'm not favoring one approach over the other. I'm wondering why we do not have both (in general).

Comment: Basically I'm saying is that doing it after register allocation is unlikely to give better results than before. So why bother with it at all if you can do it all at once before?

Comment: It is not unlikely, I have seen scope of const. prop. in the assembly generated; that's why I got curious in the first place. I'm trying to speculate what would be the trade-offs w.r.t. implementation, compilation time etc.

Comment: cont. from above: though it might be possible that performance gains are not so much as I do not have any idea performance measures.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how constant propagation after register allocation could achieve anything. Can you show us a concrete example?

Comment: @TonyK: I have posted an example to clarify my point.

Answer (score 1):

See: [Constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding)

The example given,

```
 int x = 14;
 int y = 7 - x / 2;
 return y * (28 / x + 2);
```

The value `x` is completely unused after the constant folding.  If *RA* was used first, it would create registers for `x`.  So there is a chance for some pruning before running the *RA* phase, even if the results are the same.  If there are even more variables, spills could be avoided.  These would be difficult to undo after the registers are allocated.

I think that instead of constant propagation you are thinking of [strength reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction)?  This is more in the spirit of *peephole optimizations*; or I don't understand what you mean by *constant propagation* during the *peephole* phase, which is usually a back-end portion.

Any *Constant folding* that was applied before *register allocation* should be identical, unless variables have been made constant or code was found dead; Ie the [CFG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph) has changed.<sup>[per Mystical](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial)</sup>

[SSA Elimination after Register Allocation](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~palsberg/paper/cc09.pdf) describes the LLVM structure.  I believe that the SSA could be annotated with constant values so that on *Phi elimination* unneeded moves can be avoided.  This is probably an artifact of the *SSA elimination after RA* and other compilers won't be experiencing  this issue.  A separate pass will slow compilation, so addressing the issue in existing passes would be better.  I think the following code illustrates the issue,

```
 int foo(int a, int b)
 {
    int c;
    if(a > 0)
        c = 7;
    else
        c = a * b + 10;
    return a + c;
 }
```

Upon *phi elimination* the code looks like,

```
 int foo(int a, int b)
 {
    int c;
    if(a > 0) {
        c = 7;
        return a + c;  /* Should reduce to "a+7" */
    } else {
        c = a * b + 10;
        return a + c;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I'm not disregarding const. prop. before RA. I'm trying to find a trade-off when there would be "one more" const. prop. pass after RA.

Comment: I have answered some of your questions in my EDITed response. There are passes after register allocation which expose constants to be propagated, and instructions to be removed.